# Selecting Element inside canvas tag

Tags: selenium

[image]I have to click on maps and then select one location from there. It is inside a canvas tag. How can I do that using selenium?

HTML Code -

```
<canvas class="leaflet-zoom-animated" width="3740" height="1408" style="transform: translate3d(-153px, -59px, 0px); width: 1870px; height: 704px;"></canvas>
```

Selenium is not able to click.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you share some code of what you are doing?

Comment: HTML - <canvas class="leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" width="3740" height="1408" style="transform: translate3d(-153px, -59px, 0px); width: 1870px; height: 704px;"></canvas>

Comment: Please provide the selenium code as well...

Answer (score 0):

1. To perform using Actions chains, below is an example C# code similar to Java

```
    IWebElement canvas = driver.FindElement(By.Id("TimeZoneId"));
    int xCo = canvas.Location.X;
    int yCo = canvas.Location.Y;Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.MoveToElement(canvas, 'your x coordinates' + xCo, 'your y coordinates' + yCo).Click().Build().Perform();
```

2. Try [OpenCV](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/html-canvas-testing-selenium-opencv-maciej-kusz)
3. If you are testing overlays on map. use [JavaScriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) and by adding [hooks](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polygons) to your code in order to perform actions in your Map.